# window manager overlay touch disables other apps underneath

Tags: android, overlay, android-windowmanager

I am trying to implement a hidden overlay on top of all the apps. What I am able to achieve is on swipe of the overlay view, I am able to display a dialog. But if user touch any other apps which is below my overlay, that is not working. If user do any gesture other than this swipe, my app should not interfere and affect the touch events of all other apps. Anyone have any workaround for this ?

Answer (score 1):

i hope this helps you

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

get back the touch

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```